# Google Play services API access from android service

Tags: android

I am using Google Play Services to connect the user with my app. Also I would like to sync some files in Drive. I could connect to Google API using an Activity and the GoogleApiClient interface, but I would like to keep this kind of "session" to sync files from a service.

It is possible?

Thanks

Agustin

Comment: You're probably wondering why no one has answered you by now right? SO is not a place where you get the answer served on a silver platter - sorry to disappoint you ;-) You need to show at least a little effort. What did you try so far on your own? Do you have some code? Looking the documentation for connecting to Google Play Services (https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html) the `GoogleApiClient.Builder` class it takes a `Context` (not an `Activity` and a `Service` is a `Context`, so what's the use for an `Activity`? :-)

Comment: The question  it is simple. Usually you connect / disconnect from google play service in each activity. I have followed the example and it is works inside the activity but when I use the service says: client must be connected. The code is the same in the link. I am not pretend a code solution. I only want a theorical response :). Sorry about my english

Comment: But the Google Play Services doesn't need an `Activity` to work. It only needs a `Context` which your service provides - hence this has nothing to do with the `Service` - it's something else in your code that are wrong. The error message you get is from some code you wrote, so maybe you could share that code with us? The theoretical answer to your question, is that it should work with a `Service` because the `Service` is a `Context`.